# How to provide new rest-template for every request to int-http:outbound-gateway?

Tags: spring-integration

I am facing issue with the int-http:outbound-gateway when I am passing a rest-template which holds the basic credentials at the initial time. But, if any one changes credentials in database, rest-template cannot get those updated credential dynamically.

My code,

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway  id="OutboundGateway"
                                 request-channel="sendDataToContentType"
                                 url="http://localhost:8080"
                                 expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                                 rest-template="restTemplate"/>

<bean id="httpComponentsMessageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
<property name="credentials">
    <bean class="org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
        <constructor-arg value="${fromDatabase.userName}"/>
        <constructor-arg value="${fromDatabase.password}"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
<constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <property name="httpClient" value="#{httpComponentsMessageSender.httpClient}"/>
    </bean>
</constructor-arg>
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything with the `rest-template`. There is need really just update the `credentials` on the underlying `HttpClient`.

I'd do that similar to the `org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender` code:

```
((org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient) getHttpClient())
                .getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(authScope, credentials);
```

I mean in case of changing credential in the DB you should retrieve that `#{httpComponentsMessageSender.httpClient}` in your service and call that code.

In fact the credentials are used for each request:

```
context.setAttribute(
            ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER,
            getCredentialsProvider());
    return context;
```

where it is used from the `AbstractHttpClient.doExecute()`.

So, update the credentials on the HttpClient in one place has effect for the next HTTP Request from the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`.

**UPDATE**

> But, in this approach a new httpClient instance is being passed

Right, you can use the `HttpClientBuilder` but only once, on the initialization phase. I mean you need it for the `httpClient` injection to the `httpComponentsMessageSender`.

And the reason for that is because you can pass there (`HttpClientBuilder`) your own `CredentialsProvider`. When the same `setCredentials(authScope, credentials)` can be used from your DB service.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and working solution. I am using spring 4+ version where I can see DefaultHttpClient is shows as deprecated. Would you let me know alternative class or implementation?